# Why is rsync creating a new subdirectory?

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync on Cygwin, if that matters and under a directory `c:\topDir`, I have two folders `subFolder1` and `subFolder2`. Each has about 300GB of files, some are the same and some are not, and some subdirectories are present in one folder and not in the other. It's not possible to delete `subFolder2` before copying, unfortunately.

I would like to recursively copy all the contents of `subfolder1` into `subfolder2`. From `c:\topDir`, I ran the following command,

```
rsync -ra --info=progress2 subFolder1 subFolder2
```

but it created a new subdirectory under subfolder2 before copying everything into it, 
 `c:\topDir\subfolder2\subfolder1`

What do I need to do to **copy `subFolder1`'s contents to `subFolder2` without putting them into a new subdirectory**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a trailing slash to the source directory like this:

```
rsync -ra --info=progress2 subFolder1/ subFolder2
```

As explained in [the Rsync man page under “Usage” examples](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html):

> ```
> rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp
> ```
>
> This would recursively transfer all files from the directory `src/bar` on the machine `foo` into the `/data/tmp/bar` directory on the local machine. 
>   The files are transferred in "archive" mode, which ensures that symbolic links, devices, attributes, permissions, ownerships etc are preserved in the transfer.
>
> Additionally, compression will be used to reduce the size of data portions of the transfer.
>
> ```
> rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp
> ```
>
> a trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to transfer all files from the directory `src/bar` on the machine foo into the `/data/tmp/`.
>
> A trailing `/` on a source name means "copy the contents of this directory". Without a trailing slash it means "copy the directory".
>
> This difference becomes particularly important when using the `--delete` option.

Also, be sure to test Rsync stuff like this using the `--dry-run` option. This will simply output what Rsync would do without affecting files. That way you can see exactly what will happen before you commit to it. Use it like this in your case and just remove it when it comes time to do the actual Rsync:

```
rsync -ra --info=progress2 --dry-run subFolder1/ subFolder2
```